# Getting RGB value out of negative int value

Tags: java, graphics, rgb, histogram

i had to convert from rgb to hsb so as to perform histogram equalization on an image. I have converted it back into rgb and i am getting a negative value like -158435. Can anyone please help me understand how to convert this into a colour so i can set it to my pixel? Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see how you did the conversions?

Answer (score 1):

Simply make use of the bit-shifting. It works.

```
int rgb = 0x00F15D49;

int r = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (rgb >>>  8) & 0xFF;
int b = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Then use this method
[`Color.RGBtoHSB(int r, int g, int b, float[] hsbvals);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D%29) like this:

```
float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(r, g, b, null);
```

To convert it back, simply use the other method (edited, you were right):

```
int rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(rgb));
```

Comment: So something like to this to convert it to hsb                     for (int y = 0; y<height; y++) { for (int x = 0; x<width; x++) { Color pixel = image.getPixel(x, y); int red = pixel.getRed(); int green = pixel.getGreen(); int blue = pixel.getBlue(); pixel.RGBtoHSB(red,green,blue,hsbvalues);                                                                                                                       and then      int m = pixel.HSBtoRGB(hsbvalues[0],hsbvalues[1],lum);          so i have a int m but i do know what to do to get colors value.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But, take a look at my last edit. I think you will find your needs. Color.HSBtoRGB isn't returning an integer, but a `Color` object...

Comment: thanks, i've just tried it. I keep getting and incompatible type error. Found int but expected java.awt.color

Comment: Oops!! You are right, I misread the JavaDoc. I edited my answer. Try that.

Comment: thanks, it works but i have another problem. What should the scale factor for the brightness be? For colors it is 255/width*height, however i have no idea what it would be for brightness. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The negative value appears because you are storing colors as ARGB (Alpha Red Green Blue).
The alpha channel is then often just 100% opaque, which is 255 = 0xFF.

Therefore, when the color is converted to an 32 bit int, it appears negative.

**Example:** Opaque Black = ARGB(255, 0, 0, 0) = 0xFF000000 = -16777216

Comment: Please note 0xFF is 255